# Sencha touch 2 Slide Navigation with icons

Tags: css, extjs, navigation, touch, slide

I am new to sencha touch. In our Project we are about to implement slide navigation approach.

Can anyone help me how to implement slide navigation like below image which I have shared.
[Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCFcZ.png)

I have tried some examples to implement side navigation like this
[Slide Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq6E0.jpg)

Can any one help me, how to implement navigation which I have shared in above Image.

View.js

```
Ext.define('app.view.SlideNavigation', {
    requires: ['Ext.Menu'],
    singleton: true,
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
    },
    views: ['app.view.UserSettings'],
    config: {
    },
    setMenu: function() {
        Ext.Viewport.setMenu(this.createMenu('right'), {
            side: 'right',
            reveal: true
        });
    },

    createMenu: function(side) {
        var items = [
            {
                xtype :'button',
                text: 'User Profile,
                iconCls: 'settings',
                scope: this,
                handler: function() {
                                         }
},{
                text: 'Password',
               // ui:'plain',
                //style:'background-color:white',
                iconCls: 'compose',
                scope: this,
                handler: function() {
}
},
{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Logout',
              //  ui:'plain',
               // style:'background-color:white',
                iconCls: '',
                scope: this,
                handler: function() {
                                      },
} ];
   var className = 'Ext.Menu';

        return Ext.create(className, {
            cls:'user-icons',
            items: items
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be advised that StackOverflow is not a "write my code" service. If you are in need of help, please post the code you have written so we may assist you appropriately.

Comment: Instead of actionsheet with buttons, use a list with store and records. And use another theme, either crisp or triton.

Comment: Thanks Alexnader.. Please share some example if any.

Comment: Hello, first the best way to create a component is extending from the original class.. in your way you are loosing a lot of functionality.. see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-modern/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-extend
As Alexander said, create a component extended from tree list, using a store with your menu items, here is a full example https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15ac